# python: the form of key in heaps.nsmallest

Tags: python, python-3.x

when I study python cookbook, there raised a question really puzzle me:

```
portfolio = [
       {'name': 'IBM', 'shares': 100, 'price': 91.1},
       {'name': 'AAPL', 'shares': 50, 'price': 543.22},
       {'name': 'FB', 'shares': 200, 'price': 21.09},
       {'name': 'HPQ', 'shares': 35, 'price': 31.75},
       {'name': 'YHOO', 'shares': 45, 'price': 16.35},
       {'name': 'ACME', 'shares': 75, 'price': 115.65}
]

    cheap = heapq.nsmallest(3, portfolio, key=lambda s: s['price'])
```

here we can see the 's' is not defined, but how it can work? what should I do if I don't want to use lambda?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, actually, `s` **is** defined, just not in a way you are used to define things. Look closer to this expresion:

```
key=lambda s: s['price']
```

As you can see, `s` is defined you after `lambda`, in the part `lambda s:`. An expression that won't work would be:

```
key=lambda s: a['price']
```

as you can see, now `a` is not defined. You only have to understand that the function `heapq.nsmallest` takes three parameters, and the last one is a function (in this case a lambda function), and in this case, takes a dictionary and get a specific key.

Comment: thank you so much! that makes sense